# how can t customize <GridFilterMenuItem mui react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

i want to customize the mui datagrid (Pro), i would like to render in header column
the GridFilterMenuItem, that works well, but i would like to customize the inner text, currentely that render "FILTER"

```html
<GridColumnMenuContainer
            {...other}
            currentColumn={apiRef.current.getColumn(headerName)}
            onClick={apiRef.current.hideColumnMenu}
            open
        >
              <GridFilterMenuItem
                  onClick={apiRef.current.hideColumnMenu}
                  column={apiRef.current.getColumn(headerName)}
              />
        </GridColumnMenuContainer>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV6Az.png)